# Debug AJAX Form

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, debugging

I have a `.php` file with HTML code and inside it I call another php with html file with AJAX. A form.
Apparently something with this form is wrong, or the query after it. Problem is:

- When I submit it, the page reloads, and I cannot debug my form.
- When I use `preventDefault` on my code, and prevent the form from
  submitting I cannot debug because the query is not executed yet.
- Cannot write an html message displaying the variable because after
  reload php with the form is gone.

How can I debug my code in this situation?

File1.php

```
    $(".edit-post").click(function(){
        var postid = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/admin/EditProductForm.php/",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                ajaxpostid: postid
            },
            success: function(data){
               $('#post').html(data);
            }
        });
        $("#post").show();

    });
```

EditProductForm.php

```
<?php
$ID = $_GET["ajaxpostid"];
$post = GetProduct($ID);
if(!empty($_POST)){
...query
}
?>
<html>
  <form>
  .
  .
  .
 </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

a button on form can have three types button|submit|reset , the default type is submit.

on your case, you are clicking on button which has the default type of submit, so its submitting form. that's why the page refreshes. but you want to apply Javascript instead.

so in these cases, either you apply event.preventDefault(); with the javascript code to stop form submission, or simply add type="button" to your button to explicitly say this button is going to run javascript

```
type=submit -> it means button is going to submit form date
type=reset  -> it means button is going to clear form data
type=button -> it means button is going to apply javascript

<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Why would the OP do this? What does this achieve?  A good answer will include some explanation as to why a suggested course of action will help.

Comment: hi, i edited my answer to be more declarative

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that although your HTML and Javascript might have been delivered to the workstation by PHP, it is now running in a totally separate environment with no access to PHP at all.

The PHP you're running on your server is running in the server environment, and has no access to the HTML and JavaScript running in the browser.

The two parts of your application communicate either by sending data as part of a `GET` or `POST` request when the form is submitted, or by sending and receiving messages through AJAX. It would be unusual to use both methods in one page.

Thus, you can debug the two parts separately.

Turning to your code:

Your AJAX code is triggered when your button is clicked. In the absence of any other attributes, the button will also trigger a `submit`. This is what is causing the page to reload. Since you're using AJAX to update your page you don't want it to reload, so stop it with `preventDefault();`

```
$(".edit-post").click(function(event){   // add the event parameter here
    event.preventDefault();              // Prevent the default action - the submit.
    var postid = $(this).attr("id");
    ...
```

With this done you can use the browsers tools Network tab to watch the messages, see what's being sent, and look at what response is received.

The server end of things is a little more awkward, but adding `echo` statements at appropriate places can provide useful output while debugging. Note that you don't need your AJAX script to debug the server end - a simple HTML form with the right fields will do. If you're using `GET` you could even type the URL and query string on the command line by hand and watch the results.

In your code there is a basic flaw, however.

In your AJAX code you're setting the request type to `GET` (`type: "GET",`). In your PHP script you're looking for `$_GET["ajaxpostid"];`, which is OK, but then you start looking at the `$_POST` array, which will be empty because your AJAX call used `GET`.

Now at this point, there's not enough code to be clear about what you're trying to achieve. If your SQL query is just retrieving data to populate an edit form then `GET is an appropriate method, and you shouldn't be looking at the` $_POST` array.

However, the code you've posted suggests that the `EditProductForm.php` code is generating the HTML to perform the edit. If this is the case you **don't need AJAX** at all, and you can just `submit` the form from `File1.php`. On the other hand, if you want the page to transform to an editing form without a refresh then `File1.php` needs to create the editing form and incorporate the data sent by the server, and your `EditProductForm.php` should not do that job.

Answer (score -1):

file 1(jquery):

```js
    
    $(".edit-post").click(function(){
            var postid = $(this).attr("id");
          
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "./EditProductForm.php",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {
                    ajaxpostid: postid
                },
                success: function(data){
                
                   $('#post').html(data);
                }
            });
            $("#post").show();
    
        });
```

file 2:

```html
    <?php
    if($_GET["ajaxpostid"] == "test"){
        
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fa">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
             <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="../Requirement/css/bootstrap.min.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="./index.css">
        <title>test</title>
        </head>
      <body>
    
    <h1>hello world !</h1>
    
    <script  src="../Requirement/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="../Requirement/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Requirement/hls.js/dist/hls.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php } ?>
```